# neovim + lsp-config + gopls - invoking the omnifunc removes one character before the cursor

Tags: neovim, lsp

It's a while ago, but some `PackerSync` or a neovim update is behaving like this.

So I want to invoke completion on a code like this:

[image]

Hitting `CTRL+X` and `CTRL+O` results in this:

[image]

See, after the `log` the `.` was removed, which is frustrating.

The weird thing is, that it is like this only with gopls. With lua_ls it works fine:

[image]

and invoking the omnifunc:

[image]

```
NVIM v0.10.0-dev
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```

lsp-config: v0.1.6-279-gf7922e5

gopls: golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.13.2
golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.13.2 h1:Pyvx6MKvatbX3zzZmdGiFRfQZl0ohPlt2sFxO/5j6Ro=

what could be the problem?